# Unable to populate the drop down List

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I am unable to populate a drop down list. I am fetching data from a service class function.

And I am using Ajax call and Servlet and HTML.

If you have any such examples which uses a Servlet class, Ajax and HTML. Please do add in your answer.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please include the code that is not working?

Comment: It's in my system ,right now I m posting via mobile .

Comment: I have doubt in dopost method

Comment: @Sanjeet kumar 
Can you Show me the code?
A snippet from servlet ,ajax call And html page.
then i can give any solution.

Comment: try{
List<cars> c1=getCarsName();
request.setAttribute("car",c1);
List<mfgYear> y1=getMfgYear();
request.setAttribute("year",y1);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/MyTest.HTML").forward(request,response);
Printwriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println(c1);
out.println(y1);
out.flush();
out.close();
}

Comment: This is dopost method of Servlet

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Also User following model to populate dropdown from json response**

```
     $('#dropdownID').change(function(){
        var dataString = "You input for request";

      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "ServletName",
        data : dataString,
        dataType: "json",

        // if received a response from the server
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             if(data.success){

             $.each(data, function(index, item)
                      {
                $("#selectID").append("<option>" + item.youOption + "</option>");
    }); 
          });

     });
```

Comment: Guys any suggestions

Comment: @Sanjeet  you are setting array list as attribute ,,let me know how are you interpreting response in html file!! can you share your html file